# Suggested edit that made no apparent difference to question

Tags: support, suggested-edits, revisions-list

I assume this is a network-wide issue: recently on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) I reviewed a suggested edit that I rejected because it made no apparent difference to the question. It was subsequently approved and resulted in the following diff which is what I saw when reviewing the edit:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/328449/revisions

I'm guessing it changed the character encoding in some way but I'm really not sure how I could have determined whether it was worthwhile from the information presented to me? Something I did think to do before rejecting the edit was a Google search on "СССР Parts Identification" and it came up as the number one hit so whatever the original encoding was Google didn't seem to have a problem indexing it so I can't really see any improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The edit summary gives a hint: "Fixed script"...

The edit changed the title to use the Cyrillic script letters [Es](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Es_(Cyrillic)) and [Er](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Er_(Cyrillic)), which although look identical to Latin script C and P are different letters (and a completely different Unicode characters). If you copy only the "С" or "Р" from the edited title and do a Google search you will see the difference.

As for the validity of the edit; [СССР](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A1%D0%A0) is Russian for USSR so I would say the edit was correct.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to try the single character check, looks like on the whole phrase Google handles it OK.